# How to check a log for a string and verify app status?

Tags: ansible

I am a newbie to Ansible and I want to verify if an application (non service) is running, if not, start it.  So basically look for the output of "splunkd is running".

Output of 'status' command is

```
splunkd is running (PID: 15111).
splunk helpers are running (PIDs: 15214 15420 15431 15500).
```

Also want to check said app's log file for a string "does not exists!" and if it exists restart app (until that string no longer exists in log - the log currently does rotate upon restart).   The servers in question only exists in Production and I don't feel too comfortable executing code there for the 1st time.  Below is what I have so far, I feel like the 1st block and 3rd block need editing.  Thanks for any assistance and feedback!

```
  - name: Splunk status
    command: sudo /splunk/bin/splunk status
    changed_when: false
        
  - name: Read log
    shell: cat /splunk/log/splunkd.log
    register: splunk_log

  - name: Restart if "does not exists!", exists
    command: sudo /splunk/bin/splunk restart
    until: splunk_log.stdout.find('does not exists!') == 0
    #when: splunk_log.stdout.find('does not exists!') != -1
    debug: msg="does not exists! exists, restarting"
    retries: 5
    delay: 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the first task but I think you're trying to do something like this [example of changed_when](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-changed_when-and-failed_when-examples/#How_to_use_ansible_changed_when_Statement). Also, for task three follow this [when-statement](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-changed_when-and-failed_when-examples/#How_to_use_ansible_when_Statement).